# Selecting lines forming loops (not dead ends) within network dataset using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, line, network-analyst, network, streets

I am looking for a way to select and export all segments of a network dataset, which are not dead ends.

One way to create dead end sections is to calculate dangles and select intersecting sections. But this only shows me the last segments.

I attached an image. My goal is to find all segments, which represent a loop and somehow a closed network itself.

The points are dangle points and as you can see it would only select the very last segments. My goal is to find the yellow highlighted segments.

Do you have a solution for that using ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: Which ArcGIS and Licences Version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your network into a geometric network you can use the [find loop solver](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geometric-networks/tracing-on-geometric-networks-finding-loops.htm). You can create a selection from the loops and export these into another dataset.

Comment: thanks for your advice.
It actually worked out. But I found a more straight forward way.
I converted the lines to polygons by Feature to Poly. So closed loops will be polygons and by selecting those segments which share same segments I could export these lines as well. Results are the same! But thanks for your hint!

Comment: That's an interesting alternative way to solve the issue, but it may be imperfect? Looking at example above, imagine you had a spur (dead-end road) going inwards from one of the marked yellow lines. A polygon is still created but now you have included a spur when you pass the selection back. Just something to be aware of?

Comment: Thats true! And i am aware of that.
But the Find Loops Solver didnt reply this segments either.
So this is definitely something you have to be aware of when working with infrastructure data.